# Unity webGl unable to see the main scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I build an application using Unity 2019.4
So if I try to build this application as windows application it is ok, if I try to build this application as HTML5 application, I can see this when I tun it:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

This is the web.config file that I insert in the folder of the application on IIS

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mem" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    　　　　<mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".data" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　  <mimeMap fileExtension=".memgz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　  <mimeMap fileExtension=".datagz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　  <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3dgz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
　　　　　　  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jsgz" mimeType="application/x-javascript;charset=UTF-8" />
　　　　</staticContent>
    
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
　　</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: well firstly those dont look to be the right file extensions, and second the mime types dont look to line up with the suggested file extensions as per unity requirements.  and Im not sure unity builds html5 sites? they do webgl

Comment: what should be the correct extensions?

Comment: well - it should be apparent from your build folder.. but things like .memgz, are always .mem.gz etc.. go read up on the documentation

Comment: See here (scroll down) for an IIS config sample https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-server-configuration-code-samples.html